# Programmically displaying imagecache presets no longer works

Tags: 6, media

I have noticed that recently imagecache no longer displays images when used programmatically. I have seen this happen on an existing site in which it did work at one time and on a new site (that I am currently developing). I am using the command:

```
print theme('imagecache', 'listing_thumbnail', $node->field_photos[0]['filepath'],
    $node->field_photos[0]['data']['alt'], 'Listing thumbnail', '');
```

I have tripled checked that the preset name is spelled correctly, the node attributes field_photos are correct so it should work. I have searched high and low to see if anyone else is having this problem but can't find anything. What am I missing? Why does this no longer work?

I am using Drupal 6.25 and imagecache 6x-2.0rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the problem in this particular case is that the imagecache 6x-2.0rc1 module has a regression bug in it. Reverting to the previous version restored the functionality and everything works as it should. Hopefully this will be fixed with the next release of imagecache.

Comment: Thank you for this! You've saved my sanity. Is this bug filed anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the user running the web server process has the correct permissions to write in the files directory. Imagecache writes the images into physical files and if it cannot do so, no images will be displayed.